# What is the intuition behind linearity of expectations not requiring independence?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, intuition, expected-value

I am confused as to the intuition behind the linearity of expectations not requiring events to be independent. Why is this true? I read that since the proof that shows expected values are linear does not use anything regarding independence, independence is not a requirement. I don't quite follow that step. Why would we not need to show that both independent and dependent events have this property?

This also leaves me confused with questions regarding this property. For example, `Suppose you toss a fair coin 12 times resulting in a sequence of heads (H) and tails (T). Let N be the number of times that the sequence HTHT appears.  For example, HTHT appears twice in HTHTHTTTTTTT. Find E(N)` 
The answer to this problem is `9/16`, which comes from the fact that there is a `1/16` probability that `HTHT`occurs, starting at index `n, with 1 <= n <= 9`, and the answer is `9 * 1/16`.

Why is it that we can add the probability that the string `HTHT` occurs starting at any index? I ask this because say `HTHT` were to appear in the first four flips, then the probability that `HTHT` occurs starting at the second index is zero because T was the outcome of the second index.

An explanation of the intuition of this property would be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps you could motivate the question by telling us, what is your intuition behind thinking independence has anything to do with linearity of expectation? Expectation is just an average. If I'm in business selling food and drinks, my average total sales per day is the sum of my average food sales and my average drink sales. That's counterintuitive to you? You really think it would matter if food and drink sales were independent of eachy other or not?

Comment: @bof I have rephrased the second portion of my question in the third paragraph. I hope that helps make it clearer

Comment: Why did you give an example with a sequence of 12 coin flips when you could have illustrated the same point with occurrences of HT in a sequence of 3 coin flips? Don't you think it might be easier to see what's going on in a smaller example?

Comment: @bof this was a question that I came across that caused my initial confusion, but maybe I should go back and try considering a smaller example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an intuitive argument. Imagine that you repeat your random experiment $N$ times, each time observing a new value of a random variable $X$ and a new value of a random variable $Y$. Let's denote the observed values of $X$ and $Y$ as $X_1, \ldots, X_N$ and $Y_1, \ldots, Y_N$. If $N$ is large, then
$$
\tag{1} E(X) \approx \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N X_i  \quad \text{and} \quad E(Y)  \approx \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N Y_i.
$$
But
$$
\tag{2} E(X+Y) \approx \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N X_i + Y_i.
$$
Comparing equations (1) and (2) shows that $E(X+Y) \approx E(X) + E(Y)$. And we can make the approximation as good as we like by taking $N$ to be sufficiently large. So we conclude that $E(X+Y) = E(X) + E(Y)$. Notice that in this argument we never assumed $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Answer (score 5):

It's because summation and integration are linear operations: 
$$ \sum_j (a x_j + b y_j) = a \sum_j x_j + b \sum_j y_j$$
$$ \int (a f(x) + b g(x))\; dx = a \int f(x)\; dx + b \int g(x)\; dx$$
and expected value is defined by an integral (or a sum for the discrete case).

Comment: I'm not sure I see this. Supposed $f_1$ is a PDF for a random variable $X_1$ and $f_2$ is a PDF for $X_2$. Then $E(X_1) = \int x f_1(x) dx$ and $E(X_2) = \int x f_2(x) dx$.  Since integration is a linear operation we can immediately see that $E(X_1)+E(X_2) = \int x (f_1(x) + f_2(x)) dx$. But what we need to show is that $E(X_1)+E(X_2) = \int x f_3(x) dx$, where $f_3$ is a PDF for $X_1+X_2$. How does that follow? Can you spell that out in more detail?

Comment: The problem is that you're using the same variable $x$ for different purposes.  Rather let $f(x_1,x_2)$ be a joint PDF for $X_1$ and $X_2$.
Then $E(X_1) = \iint x_1 f(x_1,x_2) \; dx_1 \; dx_2$, $E(X_2) = \iint x_2 f(x_1, x_2)\; dx_1 \; dx_2$, and $E(X_1 + X_2) = \iint (x_1 + x_2) f(x_1,x_2)\; dx_1 \; dx_2$.

Comment: Of course the statement is still true if $X_1$ and $X_2$ don't have a joint PDF (elementary treatments of the subject tend to leave out all sorts of possibilities).  The measure-theoretic version is much cleaner: let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be random variables defined on the same probability space with probability measure $\mu$.  Then $E(X_i) = \int X_i \; d\mu$ and $E(X_1+X_2) = \int (X_1 + X_2)\; d\mu$.

Answer (score 0):

if we bury a lot machinery, I'd suggest the intuition comes from (i) linearity and (ii) our ability to do conditioning

(i) tells us
$E\Big[y + X\Big]= E\Big[y\Big]+ E\Big[X\Big]=y+ E\Big[X\Big] $

(ii) tells us
$E\Big[Y + X\Big] $
$= E\Big[E\big[Y + X\big \vert Y=y\big] \Big] $
$= E\Big[E\big[y + X\big \vert Y=y\big] \Big] $
$= E\Big[E\big[y\big \vert Y=y\big] +E\big[ X\big \vert Y=y\big] \Big]$
$= E\Big[E\big[y\big \vert Y=y\big] \Big] +E\Big[E\big[ X\big \vert Y=y\big] \Big]$
$= E\Big[E\big[Y\big \vert Y=y\big] \Big] +E\Big[E\big[ X\big \vert Y=y\big] \Big]$
$ =E\Big[Y\Big] + E\Big[X\Big]$
where (i) is applied on 4th and 3rd to last lines, because when the r.v. $Y$ is conditioned to equal some scalar $y$, it behaves just like the case of (i)